# Did Anakin have an earlier lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars

In *Attack of the Clones*, when Anakin’s lightsaber(the first he is seen on-screen with) is destroyed, he exclaims:

> **Anakin:** Not again! Obi-Wan's gonna kill me.

What is Anakin referring to? Did he already break a lightsaber between the films?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_first_lightsaber - All (canon) signs point to him not having had an earlier lightsaber.

Comment: It looks like the canon material for the two of them before the clone wars is still pretty thin on the ground (pretty much just the one comic series). It doesn’t rule out the lightsaber having been damaged in some significant (but repairable) way, though frequently losing it is the most likely explanation. It does make me think the film should have him losing it one more time though, to establish the pattern.

Answer (score 28):

This is likely not a reference to him BREAKING a lightsaber, but rather to him LOSING his lightsaber. Earlier in the movie, Anakin lost his lightsaber during the chase with Zam Wesell, the bounty hunter who tried to kill senator Padme Amidala. Obi-Wan caught it and returned it to him with a scolding. Anakin's lightsaber being irreparably destroyed would probably get a far stronger reaction from Obi-Wan, especially considering the lightsaber was destroyed while he was disobeying his orders in multiple ways.

Note that both in Disney canon and in Legends canon, this was [Anakin's first lightsaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_first_lightsaber/Legends). There is no mention anywhere of Anakin having had any earlier lightsaber, and this lightsaber did not get damaged during any earlier point in the 7 years he had it.

Comment: Although this is (likely) not untrue, can you offer any evidence to back it this bold statement?

Comment: @Valorum This is hardly a bold statement. It's simply pointing out the other scene prior where Anakin lost his lightsaber.

Comment: I’m not going to say that Lucas can’t write clumsy dialog (in this film), but to me the “Not again!” implies a higher level of similarity to a previous event than that earlier “misplacing”. “Oh No!” Would not have me asking the same question...

Comment: @Valorum The best evidence I have is that this particular lightsaber is called his FIRST lightsaber in lore, and he did not have an earlier lightsaber, nor did this one get damaged before during any of the AotC prequel novel. In Legends lore, he did not have any lightsaber before this.

Comment: @Nzall -Showing *evidence* that this is his first lightsaber would improve this answer considerably.

Comment: @Valorum As requested, I've edited in a paragraph about this being his first lightsaber, including a link to the Wookieepedia article.

Comment: @Nzall - That's definitely an improvement. What would make this even better is if you quoted the primary sources rather than the wiki article.

Comment: @Valorum I don't have access to the primary sources. And even if I did, there aren't that many, just a couple of comics and a backstory novel. AFAIK it's specified nowhere in canon explicitly that this is Anakin's first lightsaber, only implied through there being no mention of other lightsabers he had. There MIGHT be a minor reference in the AotC tie-in novel for the movie in the scene where his lightsaber gets destroyed, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Nzall - His lightsaber gets destroyed in the *official novelisation* and the *junior novel* but this line doesn't appear. It gets destroyed in the *graphic novel* but it is basically a shot-for-shot remake of the film. The scene with the factory doesn't appear in the *original screenplay* at all (which also means that the *annotated screenplay* is useless)

Comment: The "Absolutely Everything" factbook states that Anakin built his first lightsaber at the age of 14, but it doesn't show it, so it could (theoretically) have been a different saber

Comment: @BenMurphy I would argue that it depends on how the Jedi are trained to think about the saber.  The bad part might not be the destruction, but the lack of control over the weapon.  Consider how bad it is in today's world for a police officer to lose control of their sidearm, even if no harm is done before it is recovered.

Comment: @CortAmmon yeah I can see that interpretation. A related question occurred to me during this: Anakin’s “attachment” to R2-D2 is frowned upon by (at least) Obi-Wan and Mace Windu, although Anakin’s justification is that R2-D2 is just an extremely competent droid(ie, a useful tool). Why is attachment to a lightsaber treated differently? (Also, Obi-Wan has lost at least 2 that we know of by the end of Attack of the Clones, too, so he’s not one to talk.)

Answer (score 0):

The real answer to this is simply: unknown.
While on the one hand, yes his *"Not again!"* line could be interpreted as a reference to his loosing it back in act one, but on the other it could just as easily be interpreted to mean he's literally destroyed his lightsaber at least once prior to this.
So far as I'm aware no story has featured just such a prior incident, though conversely neither has one categorically stated that Geonosis was the only time it happened.
Personally I'm inclined to believe that he probably did break one (or more!) as a younger padawan. This is Anakin after all and one could hardly imagine him being *less* reckless in his youth.

Comment: There are multiple canon sources that say that his lightsaber is his "first lightsaber".

Comment: Story sources or reference? The latter one should be a bit leery of since they tend to be rettconed when it suits the story content. In this case it's most likely just labelled "first" for ease of reference since "first known", which more technically correct would sound odd for an in-universe reference book. Bottom line, it remains ambiguous.

Comment: @Kris In the comic where Anakin makes his first lightsaber (at age 12, like all Jedi Padawans), AFAIK the lightsaber looks exactly the same as the one he used in the movie.